# How to change weapons?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

How can I change my characters currently equipped weapon? I have two weapon slots with two different pistols in, and I would like to use the second pistol, but I've no idea how to change weapon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical, as soon as I post my question I figure it out. Well, just in case, it's the large up and down arrows on the hud apparently!

[image]

Comment: These up and down arrows are also how you access and switch on Drones. It took me some time to figure out how to make my drones do anything...